# Issue with my CSS template when the mouse is over the tiles

Tags: javascript, css, tiles, getelementbyid, onmouseover

Here's what I want to do :
I've created one generic template that will feed several tiles.
When the mouse is over a tile, it shows a transparent-black square with an icon over the tile.
It works fine, but the problem is when i got multiple tiles using the template on the same page, no matter which tile my mouse is over, the transprent-black square is always over the first tile.

Here's my code, it's a mixed CSS/JavaScript code (it works)
I've tried to create JS function but I can't make it work.

```
 <div class="hover" style="width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        overflow: auto;"

        onmouseover="document.getElementById('tag').style.display='';"
        onmouseout="document.getElementById('tag').style.display='none';">   

<div style="
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: center; 
        background-size:27px 27px;
        background-image:url('/static/img/icons/search.png');
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 70%; 
        opacity:0.7;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        display: none;
        "
        id="tag">
</div>


 <!-- We insert a picture into the top of tile !-->
<img src='<% if (typeof(image) != "undefined") { %><%= image %><% } %>'
    align=left;
    style="height:70%;

    padding-bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;">
 <!-- We add a title-->
<h2 class="ok" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top: 15px;">
    <% if (typeof(title) != "undefined") { %><%= title %><% } %></h2>
 <!-- We add a description-->
<h4 class="mt5" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <% if (typeof(description) != "undefined") { %><%= description %><% } %></h4>
</div>
```

Cheers, and thanks by advance for the asnwer :)
Vince

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are assigning the hover effect for the element with the ID "tag".
The first item found is affected.

Try selecting each element separately.

Comment: Hey, thanks dude ! I'm new to web development so I don't really know how to select each element separately :(. I guess I need some JS coding.